# Fork, exec -> man. Doesn't work correctly

Tags: unix, process

In this case I wrote a simple prog:

```
int main()
{
  pid_t chpid;
  chpid=fork();
  if(chpid==0) // child
  {
    sleep(2);
    execlp("/usr/bin/man","/usr/bin/man","ps",NULL);
    printf("still alive\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("parent goes down\n");
  }
  return 0;

}
```

While running parent dies & in 2 seconds i get: `/usr/bin/man: command exited with status 1: pager -s`

Why does it run this way? definitely the problem is the parent's death, if I add while(1) in parent's code everything is fine.

I wrote a test-prog that writes some string to standart output every period of time. It works. Seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. A little research showed that the shell, having started my process, sets controlling terminal to it (my proc) by `setpgid()`. When it dies, the shell calls `setpgid()` again despite of all the childs that were `fork`'ed by my proc. So they are already daemons. As I found, daemons can do some output routines too, but they aren't definitely have success in it. Maybe yes, maybe no. That's why childs can still do output after their parent's death (for example if I fork a simple piriodical writong hello world program). And man understands that's smth is going to be wrng with his output and starts panic. That's the way I see it.

As to `strace`, it's quite simple: the strace is still alive during all life cycle of my programs so there is no problem for thats output.

Answer (score 1):

By exiting from parent while child is running, you have just daemonized the child. Daemons and forks thereof do not have a controlling terminal, which is a requirement for pager to run (I believe `pager -s` is `less(1)`, but check it: `man pager`).

On the other hand, just writing to STDOUT is no crime even for a daemon, although there's no guarantee anyone will be there to read the output.

For a better explanation, see "[Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html)" by Richard Stevens on process groups, sessions, and controlling terminals.

Comment: Really thanks for the link. Fantastic book, I've been looking for just like that one=) As to my question: in my case the shell is a session leader. When I run my prog, shell creates new group and sets controlling terminal accordingly, i.e. my prog has controling terminal. Than it forks and dies. The forked process doesn't change its group and therefore it must have controling terminal even after it's parent death. Therefore it mustn't become a daemon. Where am I not right?

Comment: Huh, I've tried running /bin/ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,tty,state,args from your sample -- and YES, it DOES retain controlling terminal and the like. So my answer is basically wrong.

Comment: Try executing "/usr/bin/strace", -f, "/usr/bin/man" ... and running the program with 2>file, you'll see (inside file) why pager fails.

Comment: Strace'ing man got me nothing -- man works just like it must do it.

Comment: And I did following:strace -f ./a.out > temp.txt. In temp.txt I found usual man page for ps. I can't really understand this.(

Comment: I've got this: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W99.276/assignment1/signals.html -- like, "we need process groups because only one process can be interactive at a time". I don't think I understand this clearly enough though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wait(3p)` to wait for the child to die.

Comment: The problem is to understand why it doesn't work, not just to solve it.